# How to store null in a double field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

My mongodb schema has a field of "double" data type. Sometimes, when there is no value for this field, mongo is storing it as 0.0 but I need it to store as null

My Schema:

```
db.createCollection("nulltest", {
    validator: { $jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "object",
        properties: {
            "name": {
                bsonType: "string"
            },
            "salary": {
                bsonType: "double"
                }
            }}
        }} )

1. db.nulltest.insertOne({ "name": "abc", "salary": null }) - When inserted, schema validation fails (which is expected)

2. db.nulltest.insertOne({ "name": "abc", "salary": Number(null) }) - When inserted, stores as 0.0 ("salary" : 0.0)

3. db.nulltest.insertOne({ "name": "abc", "salary": Number() }) - When inserted, stores as 0.0 ("salary" : 0.0)

4. db.nulltest.insertOne({ "name": "abc", "salary": Number("null") }) - When inserted, stored as NaN ("salary" : NaN)
```

Question:
How can I store null value in a field of double data type?
ie: "salary": null

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Update Schema to store two data type values in a field is to define it as array.

Updated schema:

```
db.createCollection("nulltest", {
    validator: { $jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "object",
        properties: {
            "name": {
                bsonType: "string"
            },
            "salary": {
                bsonType: ["double", "null"]
                }
            }}
        }} )
```